# How to load file(it is image) from parse in swift ios application?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How to load file(it is image) from www.parse.com in swift ios application? I tried as stated on the parse.com but does not work. There is an error "'PFFile?' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'". Please tell me how to upload multiple images.

```
  if let imageNews = object["imageNews"] as? PFFile {
        cell!.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")
        cell!.imageView.file = thumbnail
    }
```

Comment: Try `object.objectForKey("imageNews")` instead of `object["imageNews"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution of my error. This is below. Thank everybody.

```
  var imageFromParse = object?.objectForKey("imageNews") as? PFFile
        imageFromParse!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            var image: UIImage! = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
            cell?.imageViewCell?.image = image
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

> imageFromParse!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock(..)

I recommend you to use PFImageView to load files, especially when you load images for cell or you will have a problem with canceling loading image, as your cell are reusing.

You still should use the check for optional value: if let imageNews = .. , in case your object are not loaded.

```
if let imageNews = object.objectForKey("imageNews") as? PFFile {
   cell!.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.jpg")
   cell!.imageView.file = thumbnail
}
```

You can find more here: http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/loading-remote-images-stored-on-parse/